# Count rows based on year-month and sort it from oldest to newest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a df like this:

```
data = {'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-02'],
        'tweets':["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

df['daate'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

So I have an `object` type date and a `datetime64[ns]` type date. I want to know the counts of rows in each year-month, like two rows in 2019-01, one row in 2020-01 and 2020-02. I would also like to sort the data based on date, from the oldest to the newest. Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use groupby to count the rows

```py
df['year-month'] = df['daate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df.groupby('year-month').count()
```

```
            date    tweets  daate
year-month          
2019-01     2       2       2
2020-01     1       1       1
2020-02     1       1       1
```

here is how to sort_values,the `ascending=True` means from lowest to highest,when `False` means from highest to lowest

```py
df.sort_values(by='daate',ascending=True)
```